# Interface visual do vs 2017 com erro

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Interface visual do vs 2017 marca código em vermelho como se estivessem com erro (quando na verdade não estão) mesmo realizando o build com sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado do build:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já reiniciei o vs e windows e o problema continua.

Comment: Tenta: fechar o VS, deletar a pasta bin e obj do seu projeto e abrir o projeto de novo.

Comment: @perozzo já tentei isso.

Comment: Qual foi o problema na minha publicação para ganhar pontos negativos? O pessoal devia informar o problema para que a comunidade possa melhorar com o aprendizado.

Comment: @VictorGuedes acho que a galera não curte muito perguntas que não tenham código..

Comment: @rLinhares entendi... a bronca é colocar código pra um problema de IDE. vlw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apaguei o arquivo .suo da solução e voltou a funcionar.

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703004/visual-studio-displaying-errors-even-if-projects-build/31944875#31944875